# HTML / CSS - Placing td inside li removes left margin on li?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, html-table, margin

This is my HTML (the CSS is part of the HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            li { 
                margin-left: 30px;
            }

            .first {
                width: 100%
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class='first'>text</td>
                <td><img src='shipping3.png' width='30px' /></td>
            </tr>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='first'>text</td>
                        <td><img src='shipping3.png' width='30px' /></td>
                    </tr>
                </li>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='first'>text</td>
                            <td><img src='shipping3.png' width='30px' /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </ul>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Now even though I made the li have a margin-left, the td's inside the li's are not moved towards the left. Even when I do

```
li td {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

the td's are not moved towards the left. How do I make the td's inside the li's receive the margin-left which is given to each li?

Comment: Why are you nesting table rows within an unordered list?

Comment: This is invalid markup. Styling problems will be inherit and inconsistent. Clean up the markup (`ul` and `li` can not be children of `tr`).

Comment: @user574632 Basically I am trying to create a forum (the PHP code is removed).. Each post is represented by two td's (first td has text, second td has an image). The first post has no indent. The post can receive any amount of replies. Each reply can receive any amount of replies. The only way I could think of dynamically indenting the replies is through just adding a new list every time a user makes a reply to a reply. So a reply to a reply would be a list inside a list (which will automatically receive two indents.. you get what I mean?)

Comment: You have invalid markup.  Such invalid markup will result in undefined behavior (based on how the client browser decides to try to render it).  Note the Content Model section of [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element).  What you need is to first correct the markup and then find a solution to your indentation issues.  There's not really enough here for me to say what that solution would be.

Comment: Ok, well it doesnt sound like you are presenting tabular data, so ditch the table all together and just use floated divs - then you can use your nested lists.

Comment: right okay, we can close this question now then. Someone can just put that it is invalid markup and I'll mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment:

You have invalid markup. Such invalid markup will result in undefined behavior (based on how the client browser decides to try to render it). Note the Content Model section of [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element). What you need is to first correct the markup and then find a solution to your indentation issues. There's not really enough here for me to say what that solution would be.